# blockchain.info multi address lookup

Tags: blockchain.info, api

https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api

multi address

I know I must be an idiot but I cannot for the life of me find out how to pass in the &limit param.

I am looking to pass in a limit of 0 because I am not interested in tx, just in balance on multiple addresses.

For example in their single address lookup:
https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/1NiNja1bUmhSoTXozBRBEtR8LeF9TGbZBN?limit=0
works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested in the balance of multiple addresses I would suggest you use the following call in stead:

https://blockchain.info/balance?active=1NiNja1bUmhSoTXozBRBEtR8LeF9TGbZBN|1MrkWMnWLW53SQVQ5Pd2BsugY1F8H1oKio

But if you need to use multi address the limit flag seems to be wrong in the documentation, it should be 'n' and the minimum limit allowed seems to be 1. 0 will just return all transactions anyway.

https://blockchain.info/multiaddr?active=1NiNja1bUmhSoTXozBRBEtR8LeF9TGbZBN|1MrkWMnWLW53SQVQ5Pd2BsugY1F8H1oKio&n=1

Comment: Wow thanks, yea I had the multi address lookup working was trying to not have 50 transactions returned. How did you figure out the param was n?! It does work so thanks so much!

Oh I see you read the json response and since n seems to be used for the tx # it is likely the param used as well?

Comment: Oh wow yes :
https://blockchain.info/balance?active=1NiNja1bUmhSoTXozBRBEtR8LeF9TGbZBN|1MrkWMnWLW53SQVQ5Pd2BsugY1F8H1oKio

Is exactly what I wanted where did you find this api call however?! EDIT: wow I feel like an idiot it is simply like 2 more down from the call I was using in their api... Any idea how many addresses can be looked up at a time? (just curious)